# How to find Postback option in each TabPage

Tags: asp.net

I have Tab control which as 5 Tabs in ASP.NET, Each tab has Gridview control with dropdown, RadioButton, and Checkbox.

I want to when ever i do selection in any of the above control page is getting  postback. If page get postback in first tab, and when i go to second tab in the second tab loading also Ispostback property will be true.

Now i want to know which control is doing postback currently in tab control is there is any possibility.

And my other question is there is any possibility to check, TabPage is loading first time. I cant go with IsPostback property because of above drawback...

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net includes the ID of the control that generated the postback event in the request parameters.  It's actually in a hidden form field named _*EVENTTARGET.  A call to Request.Params["*_EVENTTARGET"] will give you the value you're looking for.  And yes, there are TWO underscores.